# converting readHTMLTable to numeric

Tags: r

I am working with readHTMLTable and am having difficulties performing calculations on the columns, as when I convert to numeric with     as.numeric  the values in the column are changed from values to rank.
Can anyone help

```
a=readHTMLTable("http://www.nhl.com/ice/standings.htm?season=20132014&type=LEA",which=3,trim=F)
> a[,5]
 [1] 54 54 52 52 51 51 46 46 46 46 43 45 42 43 39 40 38 37 38 35 37 37 38 36 36 34 35 29 29 21
Levels: 21 29 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 42 43 45 46 51 52 54
> a[,5]=as.numeric(a[,5])
> a[,5]
 [1] 16 16 15 15 14 14 13 13 13 13 11 12 10 11  8  9  7  6  7  4  6  6  7  5  5  3  4  2  2  1
```

I would like to be able to perform functions on the values of a[,5], not the ranks. such as mean(a[,5]) = (54+54+52...+21)/30, not

> mean(a[,5])
>       [1] 8.933333

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.character(a[,5]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is trying to convert a factor variable to numeric. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information).

The canonical way to handle the problem would be `as.numeric(levels(a[,5]))[a[,5]]`

However, the method I often use is `as.numeric(as.character(a[,5]))` because it's easier to remember.